# Changing static memory to dynamic C++

Tags: c++

So recently i used static memory allocation in my program but now am trying to convert it into dynamic memory, but this error occurs :

```
Ship.cpp(42,31): error C2061:  syntax error: identifier 'engines'
```

why does it need an identifier, if it is just accessing the array of objects in class Engines ? The goal is to iterate the array of engines received as a parameter and copy each element.

some codes from my  Ship.cpp:

```
    Ship::Ship()
    {
        setShipEmpty();
    }
    void Ship::setShipEmpty()
    {
        m_type[0] = '\0';
        m_engCnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
            m_engines[i].setEmpty();

        }
    }
Ship::Ship(const char* sType, const Engine* engines, int sizeOfEngine)
    {
        if (sType != nullptr && strlen(sType) > 0 && strlen(sType) < TYPE_MAX_SIZE && engines[0].get() > 0 && sizeOfEngine < 10) 
        {
            setShipEmpty();
            m_type = new char[strlen(sType) + 1];
            strcpy(m_type, sType);
            m_engCnt= sizeOfEngine ;
        
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfEngine; i++) {
                m_engines[i] = new engines; <---- what am i doing wrong here?
            }
        }
        else {
            setShipEmpty();
        }
    }
```

The header file for ship

```
    class Ship
    {
        Engine* m_engines = nullptr;
        char* m_type;
        int m_engCnt;
...
}
```

some codes from my  engine header

```
class Engine
    {
        double m_size;
        char m_type[TYPE_MAX_SIZE+1];
public:
        Engine();
        Engine(const char*,double);
        ....
}
```

Engine.cpp

```
    void Engine::setEmpty()
    {
        m_type[0] = 0;
        m_size = 0;
    }

    Engine::Engine()
    {
        setEmpty();
    }

    Engine::Engine (const char* type, double size)
    {
        setEmpty();
        strcpy(m_type, type);
        m_size = size;
    }
```

In the Engine class i left it static , would i also need to turn this into a dynamic or can i just leave it?

Comment: What are you hoping `m_engines[i] = new engines` will do?  Copy the pointer?  (The same one every time?) ... or create a new `Engine` from the input `engines`?

Comment: @donkopotamus i was trying to iterate the array of engines received as a parameter and copy each element

Comment: You should not use raw pointers and `new`. There are standard containers for managing dynamic memory

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the code below:

```
m_engines[i] = new engines;
```

You never declared what engines is or what it does. You also do not have a constructor for engines so you cannot create an Engines object..... It uses default constructor, usually we add * after the item to indicate that it is dynamic.

Comment: Sorry, i should of added the other code as well but there is a custom constructor that i have created, it is just that their is lots of code so i try to minimize it to the source of the problem.

Comment: Kinda hard to know if theres a problem in the custom constructor if you do not post it.....

Comment: The problem seems to come from the constructor in ship.cpp when i declared new engine , how do i go about this ? Im trying to create a dynamic memory for m_engines.

Comment: The thing is that you need to do engines() with the constructor value so you can do m_engines[i] = engines(), you need to create an object of engines and call the constructor before you can allocate space for it.....

Comment: so i did do that but it is asking for a type identifer, im not sure what that would be since it is a reference to the class Engine.

Comment: Did you fix the line through, that line is not gonna work as it stands.....

Comment: @YunfeiChen The poster certainly **has** declared what `engines` is, its an `Engine*` ... in this context it needs to be treated as an array and presumably copied (`Engine(engines[i])`)

Comment: Please note that C++ is case sensitive, engines is not the same is Engine......

Comment: the error is this : Ship.cpp(42,31): error C2061:  syntax error: identifier 'engines'

Comment: i've updated the post to display both default constructor from class Engine and class Ship.

Comment: I am asking about the engines constructor not the Engine and Ship constructor, where did you define this: engines object???

Comment: sorry, i figured it out " Engine *m_engines = new Engine[sizeOfEngine]